# How can I create a sub class when given a base class in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

The typical way to do subclassing in Python is this

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base = 1

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sub = 2
        super().__init__()
```

And this allows me to create an instance of type Sub that can access both `base` and `sub` properties.

However, I'm using an api that returns a list of `Base` instances, and I need to convert each instance of `Base` into an instance of `Sub`. Because this is an API that is subject to change, I don't want to specifically unpack each property and reassign them by hand.

How can this be done in Python3?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but why don't you use `*args` and `**kwargs`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert (inherit) parent to child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030412/how-to-convert-inherit-parent-to-child-class)

Comment: @Asocia Sounds like you have a solution, feel free to answer the question.

Comment: @PM77-1 It doesn't look like it.

Comment: So the base objects are already instantiated?

Comment: @jordanm yes. The API returns a list of Base instances.

Comment: You'll need to write a function that knows how to turn a `Base` object into a `Sub` object. Perhaps this can be done in `Sub.__init__` or perhaps you write a class method in `Sub` that knows how. Or even just a stand-alone function. Alternately, perhaps `Sub` shouldn't inherit from `Base` at all and just do composition by keeping a `Base` member variable. Lots of choices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*args` and `**kwargs` if you don't want to hard code the name of the arguments.

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c="keyword_arg"):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sub = 2
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


bases = [Base(1, 2, "test") for _ in range(10)]
subs = [Sub(**b.__dict__) for b in bases]
```

Note that this assumes that all the properties of `Base` is given as arguments to the `Base`.